# SQL queries for COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Sample Data][image: My result and Expected result]

This is the SQL Code I wrote:

```
 SELECT movie-name, genre, theatre-or-dvd
 FROM MyFavs__MOVIE
 WHERE  genre  ='action' AND  theatre-or-dvd  = 'theatre'
 GROUP BY  movie-name 
 HAVING COUNT(genre) >= 3
```

How do I actually make it only display the movie name?

Comment: Um... Remove genre and theater-or-dvd from your SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT movie-name FROM MyFavs__MOVIE
WHERE genre ='action' AND theatre-or-dvd = 'theatre'
GROUP BY movie-name
HAVING COUNT(genre) >= 3 ;
```

You just have to select whatever you wanted to be displayed and you are give any condition to any column present in table .

For example :

```
Select name from school where age = 10 ;
```